# NodeJS (libuv) kqueue(): Too many open files in system

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a simple HTTP server using node's `net` module. When I test the throughput using `bombardier`, node's HTTP module handles every connection without a problem, but `net` module fails instantly. My question is, how does node's `http` handles new connection or connection pooling? Example:

```js
const http = require("http");

http
  .createServer((_, res) => {
    res.end();
  })
  .listen(4000);
```

```js
const net = require("net");

net
  .createServer((socket) => {
    socket.end("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
  })
  .listen(4000);
```

Then I run `bombardier -c 126 -n 1000000 http://localhost:4000` and `http` runs wonderful but `net` throws:

```
(libuv) kqueue(): Too many open files in system
node:tty:94
    throw new ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED(ctx);
    ^

SystemError [ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED]: TTY initialization failed: uv_tty_init returned ENFILE (file table overflow)
    at new SystemError (node:internal/errors:251:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:336:7)
    at new WriteStream (node:tty:94:11)
    at createWritableStdioStream (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:47:16)
    at process.getStderr [as stderr] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:134:12)
    at console.get (node:internal/console/constructor:216:44)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:333:50)
    at console.warn (node:internal/console/constructor:368:61)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/brielov/Work/Self/speedtest/net.js:8:37)
    at Server.emit (node:events:365:28) {
  code: 'ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED',
  info: {
    errno: -23,
    code: 'ENFILE',
    me⏎
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`http` module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) has the concept of the [Agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options), which implements a connection pool. If you do not specify it, you get the global default agent ([http.globalAgent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent)).

In the [`net` module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), which is more low-level, you need to manage the sockets yourself. One way to avoid running out of sockets in your example, is to destroy the socket once the request is done:

```
const net = require("net");

net
  .createServer((socket) => {
    socket.end("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
    socket.destroy();
  })
  .listen(4000);
```

Note that from a performance perspective, always calling destroy might not be optimal. Reusing connections and implementing a pool is a good idea. But for understanding why the original implementation quickly exhausts the resources, the missing destroy call should be the reason. Other libraries, which operate on a higher abstraction will implement that functionality under the hood.

Another way to deal with exceeding the socket limit of the system, is to limit the connection inside the `net` module by overriding [server.maxConnections](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_maxconnections). Relying on that functionality alone is not recommended. It will eliminate the exception that you get, but the server will start rejecting all incoming requests once the limit is exceed. Thus, the effect is similar: the server is down.

Comment: Thanks, that seems reasonable. What would be the best way to implement the notion of an Agent using the net module or what other performance improvements can be made besides socket destroy?

Comment: @brielov Depends on the protocol. If you want to implement a HTTP client from scratch, then implementing keep-alive could improve performance. For other use cases where TCP sockets are used, you can look what popular libraries are doing (e.g. database connectors).  What I see is that they open multiple TCP sockets, try to reuse the same connections. Only if there are errors, they will destroy them. (Of course, if you want to implement a HTTP server or client, switching to the http module or some well-tested library makes most sense.)